# Create a URL that disables Deeplinking

Tags: ios

I have a mobile app with deeplinking mapped. For example `www.my-watch-shopping.com/red` links to a related page on the app that consists of red watches.

Right now, I have a requirement where if a user clicks on `www.my-watch-shoppping.com/blue`, it links to a **webpage** on the iPhone, not to the deeplinked page on the app.

Is there a way to do so? In other words, can I create a URL that does not deeplink to the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you can launch the URL (in mobile Safari) *from* the app. Even better, respond by opening a SFSafariViewController in your app.